# extract location of tweet from twitter

Tags: java, twitter, twitter-oauth

if the location of a tweet is not available there is any other idea to extract location 
i have tried to extarct location from friends tweet but it was not successsful..if the tweet is send from a mobile we track it using geolocation but if tweet is send from a computer we could not extract it..i am using java language...i have extracted the tweets related to the query..and i extarct the location of tweet if its send from a mobile phone.but if its send from a desktop computer we are not getting the place name..

Comment: If you don't give source code examples and ask concrete problems, you are not getting any useful answers.

Comment: If the location is disabled by user, you can't retrieve it.

Comment: sometimes user will explicitly given some location in his tweet..so i am planning to extract unigrams from tweets..but when i am trying to use this method am getting longitude and latitude for each word so each word is condisered as location..i have used a google location founder and i hope that only those words whic a location will get the longitude and latitude but i was not successful